# Dealing with two screens and one activity indicator in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, background, nsthread, uiactivityindicatorview

I have 3 screens on my app.First is login. Second is search and third is process the task.
On login i retrieve data from a web service. It returns data in XML format. So the data is considerably large. So i am doing that task on a background thread like this to stop Mainthread freezing up on me:

```
-(BOOL)loginEmp
{
 .....some computation
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                                 (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
            [self getAllCustomerValues];
        });
}
 -(void)getAllCustomerValues
{
   ....more computation.Bring the data,parse it and save it to CoreData DB.
   //notification - EDIT

NSNotification *notification =[NSNotification notificationWithName:@"reloadRequest"
                                                            object:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification : notification];

}
 //EDIT

//SearchScreenVC.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 ....some computation
    [self.customerActIndicator startAnimating];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(stopActivityIndicator)
                                             name:@"reloadRequest"
                                           object:nil];
  }
 - (void)stopActivityIndicator
{
[self.customerActIndicator stopAnimating];
self.customerActIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
self.customerActIndicator.hidden =YES;
NSLog(@"HIt this at 127");
}
```

So on condition that login was successful, i move to screen 2. But the background thread is still in process( i know because i have logs logging values) . I want an activity indicator showing up here (2nd screen)telling user to wait before he starts searching. So how do i do it?How can i make my activity indicator listen/wait for background thread. Please let me know if you need more info.Thanks

EDIT: so I edited accordingly but the notification never gets called. I put a notification at the end of getAllCustomerValues and in viewDidLoad of SearchScreen i used it. That notification on 2nd screen to stop animating never gets called. What is the mistake i am doing.?Thanks

EDIT 2: So it finally hits the method. I dont know what made it to hit that method. I put a break point. I wrote to stop animating but it wouldn't. I wrote hidesWhenStoppped and hidden both to YES. But it still keeps animating.How do i get it to stop?

Comment: You are logging values, so presumably you know when your parsing is complete. Typically, I would use an `NSNotification` at that point to let the UI know that it can allow searching.

Comment: At the end of the getAllCustomerValues process, call a method on the main thread that indicates the process is completed. Either by sending out a notification, or setting a flag. The notification would be you best bet.

Comment: @livingtech. I added the code for notification. Can you take a look at it and tell me what is the mistake there.

Comment: @Bergasms. I went the notification way. Can you take a look at it and tell what is wrong there.

Comment: Hides when stopped is something you can set in the nib, if you want. Is the log HIt this at 127 coming out? If yes, put in the following line and tell me what it logs.     NSLog(@"[%@ %@] Is Main Thread? %@",NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),[NSThread isMainThread]?@"YES":@"NO");   also log the value of self.customerActIndicator to make sure it is a non null value. You may have not connected the indicator to the outlet correctly

Comment: @Bergasms. The output is this: Is Main Thread? NO

Comment: That's your problem, you cannot update the UI from a background thread, it has to be the main thread. I've posted an answer down below, which should hopefully solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if it is not the main thread, put the following in and that should fix it.

```
- (void)stopActivityIndicator
{
      if(![NSThread isMainThread]){
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopActivityIndicator) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
          return;
       }

 [self.customerActIndicator stopAnimating];
  self.customerActIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
   self.customerActIndicator.hidden =YES;
  NSLog(@"HIt this at 127");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you put your background operation into a separate class and then set a delegate on it so you can alert the delegate once the operation has completed?

I havent tried this, its just an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a delegate pointing to your view controller & a method in your view controller like:

```
- (void) updateProgress:(NSNumber*)percentageComplete { 
}
```

And then in the background thread:

```
float percentComplete = 0.5; // for example
NSNumber *percentComplete = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:percentComplete];

[delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgress:) withObject:percentageComplete waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I declared updateProgress method in my FirstScreen.h file like this protocol BackgroundThreadFinished
- (void) updateProgress :(NSNumber *)percentComplete;
end. SO at the end of background thread i am calling that like you did and it is showing an error saying "no know instance method or selector 'performSelectorOnMainThread...'. How to do it?

Comment: You need to declare your delegate as :`@property (assign) NSObject*<myDelegate> delegate;`
Note the use of NSObject* instead of the usual 'id'. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499343/compiler-gives-warning-on-performselectoronmainthreadselectordelegatemethod)